# safely empty all drupal cache in SQL

Tags: 8, caching

what tables related to drupal cache can be safely delete using SQL and how to be sure to empty it entirely?

It seems i have reminiscence of ancien block configuration when i empty cache using back office or drush cr

Comment: `drush cr` will do this?

Comment: it does not apparently

Comment: If the duplicate doesn't answer your question please update this one with what didn't work and ping me to re-open it. Thanks